# JavaFX: Display image in ListView without breaking selection model

Tags: java, image, listview, javafx, observablelist

#### Issue

I want to display a list that contains text and an image. I am able to do that, but the selection model is funky. When I select an item in the list with my mouse, it seems like the entire listview element is selected. When I use the arrow keys, the selection model works fine.

#### My code

In my controller I have `ObservableList<Game> gameList`. The Game class looks like this:

```
public class Game {
    private String name;
    private Image image;
}
```

#### Example from old solutions on Stack Overflow

When searching for a solution on how to display the image and name, I found many Stack Overflow solutions that used the `setCellFactory` method like the code snippet below:

```
listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImage(/*Some image*/);
                    setText(game.getName());
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
```

#### My attempt for a solution

However, the image that I want to display is stored in the Game object in my ObservableList. From my understanding, the `String item` parameter above is the Game objects `toString` method, but I want access to the entire Game object when making my custom ListCell. I tried to alter that solution to get access to the entire Game object instead. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public ListView<Game> listView;

    public ObservableList<Game> gameList;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        gameList = FXCollections.observableList(/*List of games*/);
        listView.setItems(gameList);
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Game game, boolean empty) {
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImage(game.getImage());
                    setText(game.getName());
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Result

With the code above, I'm able to display each Game and it's name in my ListView.
[image]

#### The issue that I'm trying to fix

The list is displayed exactly like I want, but the selection model seems to be broken.
I use `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` to fetch the selected Game. When I use my mouse to select an item, the method above returns null. This is what it looks like when I left click on the "Other game" item in the list:
[image]

However, I can use my arrow keys to select any item in the list I want. When I do that, the selected Game from my ObservableList is returned.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: You forgot to call `super.updateItem(...)` in the original list cell version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `ListCell.updateItem(...)` method handles selection, among other things. So you need to be sure to call it.

From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem(T,boolean)):

> It is **very important** that subclasses of Cell override the
> updateItem method properly ... Note in this code sample two important
> points:
>
> 1. We call the super.updateItem(T, boolean) method. If this is not done, the item and empty properties are not correctly set, and you are
>    likely to end up with graphical issues.
> 2. ...

So you need:

```
listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Game game, boolean empty) {

       // call default implementation:
       super.updateItem(item, empty);

       if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(game.getImage());
            setText(game.getName());
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

I guess the big lesson here is to read the documentation properly. I had looked at the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory(javafx.util.Callback)) for ListView, but skipped right to the method I was working with. Read the section "Customizing ListView Visuals" at the top would've taken me right to the answer.